# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when creating two ComboboxItems functions in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, nullreferenceexception

I´m all out of ideas here

The thing is that Im using two comboboxes and I want to get values from both comboboxes to show content in DataGrid in wpf.

I have this function that gets values from both comboboxes. This works well.

```
private void cboxYearChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem typeItemYear = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
        string valueYear = typeItemYear.Content.ToString();

        ComboBoxItem typeItemMonth = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        string valueMonth = typeItemMonth.Content.ToString();
}
```

But then I want to create another function to check for changes on the other combobox:

```
private void cboxMonthChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem typeItemYear = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
        string valueYear = typeItemYear.Content.ToString();

        ComboBoxItem typeItemMonth = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        string valueMonth = typeItemMonth.Content.ToString();

}
```

I can build, but when I run this I get the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on the ComboBoxItem typeItemYear = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem; line in the cboxMonthChange function

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem is null until something is selected. Unless they both change at the same time (which is not possible as these events are fired in sequence), either the type cast on comboBox1.SelectedItem or comboBox2.SelectedItem will throw an exception.

Check if SelectedItem is set the methods.
Or use another cast, like:

ComboBoxItem item1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
if (item1 != null)
{
  // do something
}

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code formatting. The menu was not visible on my phone :-)

Comment: The later options did not work. What do you mean by checking if SelectedItem is set the methods ?

Answer (score 0):

1) you should not refer to control's name within the code whenever possible.
So you can know, for instance, which ComboBox was changed within a SelectionChanged
handler by casting the `Sender` to a `ComboBox`.
2) but in such a simple case, just use public properties and bind them to
your ComboBox : all will get done with no code.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="YearSelectCB" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedYear}">
<ComboBox x:Name="MonthSelectCB" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth}">
```

(you can set the DataContext of the window in several ways, for instance in the 
window loaded event handler (DataContext=this) )